Redshift unexpected result with psycopg2 for query [INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM <VIEW> ] - writing 0 records into Target table
Come across a weird issue with the Redshift [Insert into.. select..] called from the Airflow DAG Task. We have a DAG definition with 5 sequential tasks
Task 1: Truncate temp_table
SQL : TRUNCATE temp_table;
Task 2: Load 1-day data from source_table1 using view_1 into temp_table
SQL: INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM view_1 
Task 3: Load temp_table data into fact_table_1
SQL;  INSERT INTO fact_table_1 SELECT \* FROM temp_table
Task 4: Load 1-day data using view_2 (built from source_1 and source_2) into target_table_1
SQL: INSERT INTO target_table_1 SELECT \* FROM view_2
Task 5: Load 1-day data using view_3 (built from source_2 and source_3) into target_table_2
SQL: INSERT INTO target_table_2 SELECT \* FROM view_3 
The Issue:

The DAG and all tasks are marked as successful in Airflow.

Redshift query history shows the query IDs as successful.

However, target_table_1 remains empty after Task 4, even though view_2 returns data.

Running the same INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... query from a SQL client successfully inserts records into target_table_1.


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the schema (columns and data types) of target_table_1 matches the output of view_2.

Ensured that no filters in the view_2 definition are restricting data at the time of the DAG run.


Requesting Assistance:
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Redshift inserts within Airflow? Any advice on further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. We're particularly interested in understanding why the insert works from a SQL client but not within the Airflow DAG.

I suspect that the issue is with the sequential nature of how these are running.  Redshift uses MVCC (Multiversion concurrency control - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) where transactions can see different data even when running at the same time.
You bench session is by definition a single transaction or at least strictly enforcing order of commits.  This is key - when are these tasks committed to the database with respect to the next task's transaction beginning?
Go look at the query logs and see if the transactions running these tasks are overlapped in time.  Other transactions will see versions of tables at the time they start but data updates from other sessions isn't available until those transactions COMMIT their results.  If the timing is really close you will want to look at the time that sourcing tasks' updates are fully committed in the database as compared to the time that consuming transactions start.
Also, if these views are materialized views you will want to see the timing of their updates as well.
Airflow is flexible and powerful but this can lead to thing executing not quite the way you expect.
